# Cyclic Group Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Having trouble understanding the proof that: 
If $H:=\langle h \rangle$ then, $H \cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ for some $m>0$.
Here is the proof:
[image]

It begins from Suppose $N\neq0$.....

I'm confused at the "Minimality" party.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: It looks like the first part of the proof is missing. Is $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to H$ defined by $\phi(n)=h^n$ and $N=\ker\phi$?

Comment: My apologies, I should have stated this. I cut of the proof  defining these to emphasise the part that I am having trouble with. But yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define $N$, but from context it should be $N=\{n\in\mathbb Z, h^n=1\}$.
If $N\neq\{0\}$, you can take the minimal positive element $m$ in $N$ (because if $x\in N$ then $-x\in N$).
It is clear that any multiple $km$ of $m$ is also in $N$, as $1^k=1$.

It remains to show that these are the only ones, i.e. $N=m\mathbb Z$. This is taken care of by the euclidean division: if there is one which is not a multiple of $m$, the division in the proof show that there is $r<m$ in $N$, contradicting the fact that we took $m$ the smallest positive element of $N$. So we can conclude that $N=m\mathbb Z$.

Finally, it is easy to see that $H=\{1,h,\dots,h^{m-1}\}\cong\mathbb Z/{m\mathbb Z}$